# LogPrint() output location?

Tags: bitcoind, logging

Where can I check the output logs generated from `LogPrint()` statements in the `bitcoind` source code.

PS: Please do not confuse this with the `LogPrintf()` statement, which logs the output into `debug.log` file.

Comment: Have you set the right `-debug` option in your bitcoin.conf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LogPrint` and `LogPrintf` are very similar.

Mind the definiton: `#define LogPrintf(...) LogPrint(NULL, __VA_ARGS__)`

`LogPrint`'s will only end up in your `debug.log` when enabling the corresponding category. Enabling works over the `-debug` arg.

`-debug=mempool,net` would output all `LogPrint("mempool",...)` or `LogPrint("net",...)` to the debug log, or to stdout if `-printtoconsole` has been enabled.